# Facebook escaped json with Parce.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Im reading a Facebook page feed in json, like:
   `https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=237173582992285`

The response comes escaped... How to unescape the special characters and other things?!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript should convert the unicode into a readable String. You could use PHP's `html_entity_decode()` for the HTML entities.